# Rails Showing Has_Many Linked Objects Photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, photos

I can bring in Companies linked Events data, but am not able to bring in the photo that is linked to that event.

Company has_many Events & 
Event has_many Photos

**Currently my code in Company/Show looks like**

```
<% if @company.events.exists? then %>
<% @company.events.offset(1).each do |event| %>
 <li><h3><%= link_to "#{event.name}", {:controller => "events", :action => "show", :id => event.id}, :rel => "external" %></h3>
<p>By <%= event.artist %></p></li>
<%= image_tag event.photo.photo.url(:large) %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
  <p> There are no current events attached</p>
 <% end %>
```

**Company Controller**

```
 def show
   @company = Company.find(params[:id])
 end
```

I am using Paperclip for my Images. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code form Event Model (Keep in mind I am trying to access from Company)

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :artist, :starttime, :startdate, :finishdate,   :company_id, :photos_attributes
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :photos
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:photo].blank? }
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

     end
```

Comment: At the moment I have

           @event = Event.where(:company_id => :id, :order => 'DESC')

Comment: At the moment I have in my controler

              '@event = Event.where(:company_id => (params[:id]))'


When I call this in my Show action

'<%= image_tag @event %>'


The results is a blank image and this shows in the HTML


'<img alt="#&lt;activerecord::relation:0x102eca560&gt;" src="/assets/#&lt;ActiveRecord::Relation:0x102eca560&gt;" />'

Comment: You have not setup Paperclip properly with your Event model. Paste the code for that association and edit your question.

Comment: Have updated the question with Event Model, thanks for looking at this !

Comment: In your above comment too, you are using `'<%= image_tag @event %>'`, which instead should be @event.photo or whatever name you are using for your Image model.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {...}
```

part in you `Event` model.

Refer to this [Simple Example of Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Usage), and post here if you still face any problems.

Comment: Hi Jatin, thanks for the reply, unfortunately it's a little more complicated then that, Photo has it's own model as it deals with a large number of images which belong to Event, has_attached_file is stored in the photo model which works perfectly when in Events. Company also has images which work great when in Company. It's just getting that first image from the Event database that is a pain. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I can now see that it's fairly complicated. So, by what you are saying, photos(indirectly images) for both event and company are accessed correct. It's only when you access company-> event -> photo -> image, it fails.

Comment: Is it only the first image that is in-accessible, or all of them? Try your hands on console, to see if every association in the above mentioned chain is correct. I can only help you this much at the moment. Happy debugging ;)

Comment: Thanks Jatin, non of the images are accessible at the moment. I will try every association I can think of and post back if I find it. It must be in there somewhere!